# How to check if changes on multiple select boxes happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have 2 select dropdown boxes. I need to do many iterations if options were selected.

My select boxes:

```
<select id="time_period">
    <option value="day" selected>Day</option>
    option value="month">Month</option>
</select>

<select id="site">
    <option value="google" selected>Google</option>
    option value="bing">Bing</option>
</select>
```

I want to check if an option from just `#time period` was selected or an option from `#site` or even if options from both were selected.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hmm. Can you tell more detail about your question please? Are your objective is whenever option #time_period or #site change trigger your script? Or you want to set time for waiting before execute your script? Let say in three second if site and time_period change then execute my script. so your script just trigger once not every time select option change. Make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **onchange** method

```js
(function() {

  var time_period, site;

  document.getElementById("time_period").onchange = function() {
    time_period = document.getElementById("time_period").value;
    console.log(time_period);
    checkBothSelected();
  };
  document.getElementById("site").onchange = function() {
    site = document.getElementById("site").value;
    console.log(site);
    checkBothSelected();
  };

  function checkBothSelected() {
    if (site && time_period) {
      console.log('Both Selected!');
    }
  }

})();
```

```html
<select id="time_period">
  <option value="day" selected>Day</option>
  <option value="month">Month</option>
</select>

<select id="site">
  <option value="google" selected>Google</option>
  <option value="bing">Bing</option>
</select>
```

Using **onChange** property

```js
var time_period, site;

function onSelection(e) {
  if (e.id == 'time_period') {
    time_period = e.value;
  } else if (e.id == 'site') {
    site = e.value;
  }
  console.log(e.value);
  checkBothSelected();
}

function checkBothSelected() {
  if (site && time_period) {
    console.log('Both Selected!');
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="time_period" onChange="onSelection(this)">
  <option value="day" selected>Day</option>
  <option value="month">Month</option>
</select>

<select id="site" onChange="onSelection(this)">
  <option value="google" selected>Google</option>
  <option value="bing">Bing</option>
</select>
```

Using **addEventListener**

```js
(function() {

  var time_period, site;

  document.getElementById('time_period').addEventListener('change', function() {
    time_period = this.value;
    console.log(time_period);
    checkBothSelected();
  });
  
  document.getElementById('site').addEventListener('change', function() {
    site = this.value;
    console.log(site);
    checkBothSelected();
  });

  function checkBothSelected() {
    if (site && time_period) {
      console.log('Both Selected!');
    }
  }
})()
```

```html
<select id="time_period">
  <option value="day" selected>Day</option>
  <option value="month">Month</option>
</select>

<select id="site">
  <option value="google" selected>Google</option>
  <option value="bing">Bing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How do I check if both were selected?

Comment: @noob you can maintain 2 variables to keep track of your checkboxes and on value change, check if both variables are having values. This is one way of doing this. Alternately, you can also check on change if the other checkbox has value. I have updated the code to demonstrate the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a function and check for the selected value from each of the `select` box

```js
function getSelectedRadio() {
  let getTimePeriod = $('#time_period').val();
  let site = $('#site').val();
  // when both are selected
  if (getTimePeriod && site) {

  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="time_period">
  <option value="day" selected>Day</option>
  <option value="month">Month</option>
</select>

<select id="site">
  <option value="google" selected>Google</option>
  <option value="bing">Bing</option>
</select>

<button type='btn' onclick='getSelectedRadio()'>Click</button>
```